# Python date.today() doesn't return local date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am in EST and trying to use `date.today()`, but it is returning the next day. The docs state it should be local time. Does anyone know how I can get it to return my local (EST) date?

> classmethod date.today() Return the current local date. This is
>   equivalent to date.fromtimestamp(time.time()).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects

UPDATE: To clarify, it works most of the time, except when I tried around 10 pm EST. I checked my timezone with `time.strftime('%X %x %Z')` and it looks like UTC. How do I get today's date given the situation? Note that I would like to keep the system UTC while getting the date in EST.

Comment: Do other `datetime` methods give the wrong date/time?

Comment: Works correctly for me on Windows, have you checked your timezone settings? Note that if you change your timezone settings you need to restart Python command line for new settings to take effect.

Comment: It works totally fine, i have checked in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Does `datetime.datetime.now()` give you the. current time? What about `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`? Is it -5 hours from now?

Comment: yeah, it's a timezone issue. Updated my question. Given that my timezone is set to UTC, how do I get today's date in EST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#pytz-world-timezone-definitions-for-python):

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from pytz import timezone

datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

Note that the [python datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) explicitly recommends `pytz` (but also contains an example which works "most of the time"):

> pytz
>
> The standard library has no tzinfo instances, but there exists a third-party library which brings the IANA timezone database (also known as the Olson database) to Python: pytz.
>
> pytz contains up-to-date information and its usage is recommended.

To explictly convert this to a `date`:

```
date.fromtimestamp(datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern')).timestamp())
```

Or if you're using python < 3.3 (because [`datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) was released 4 years ago so earlier versions may not have it):

```
from datetime import timezone as datetime_timezone
now = datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern'))
ts = (now - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime_timezone.utc)).total_seconds()
date.fromtimestamp(ts)
```

Comment: With this, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`

Comment: @FullStack [`datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) was introduced in 3.3. Maybe you need to update your python to use it. The docstring also contains a variant on how to compute it directly if you don't want to update. Note that `dt` represents your object. I'll update the answer.